# Tag deletion request

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

By mistake I created the [14th-wave-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/14th-wave-antenna).

I did not realize that the tag box would not accept the `/` that I inserted, and so it created `14th` not `1/4th`.

Could someone please delete the tag? I have created a replacement [quarter-wave-antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quarter-wave-antenna) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag has no questions and no tag wiki, so as long as nobody else uses it, it will be purged automatically by the system fairly soon. I don't know exactly how often automatic tag purges happen, but I would expect it to be gone by this time tomorrow.